# Option greeks as dollar P&L

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks, sensitivities

If I write the value of an option as O(S, K, T, V), where S is the underlying price, K is the strike, T is the time to expiry and V the implied volatility, how can I compute the dollar amount that I am expected to gain or lose based on specific movements in some of the variables? 
I know this is what the greeks should tell me and if I use Black and Scholes formula, there are equations for each of the greeks of interest. 
But I am not sure how to use them to express the move in dollar amount. 
Let's say that the underlying S moves 1% and that implied volatility moves 1% (in terms of volatility points, i.e. not relative move).

If I want the $ P&L associated to the delta, I can calculate the delta as:

**Delta = O(S*1.01, K, T, V) - O(S, K, T, V)**

i.e. the difference in option value if the underlying moves up by 1%. 
For Vega I can do:

**Vega = O(S, K, T, V+1%) - O(S, K, T, V)**

But what if I want to measure the P&L given by gamma, vanna and volga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *raw* Greeks so to speak $-$ e.g. from [Wiki - European Option Greeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks) $-$ usually represent (broadly speaking) the $ amount lost per **+1 absolute move** in the respective risk-factor.

So for example, if your Spot-Delta is
   $$\text{Delta} = \Delta \approx O(S+1, K, T, V) - O(S, K, T, V)$$
and spot moves **relatively** by $x$ (say 1%) then your PnL is
   $$\text{Delta PnL} = \Delta \cdot S \cdot x = \Delta \cdot S \cdot 0.01$$
because $S \cdot x$ is the **absolute move** that Spot undergoes.

For completeness, for Spot-Gamma this looks as follows:
   $$\text{Gamma} = \Gamma \approx O(S+1, K, T, V) - 2\cdot O(S, K, T, V) + O(S-1, K, T, V)$$
   $$\text{Gamma PnL} = \frac12\cdot \Gamma \cdot (S \cdot x)^2 = \frac12\cdot\Gamma\cdot (S \cdot 0.01)^2$$

Note that the $\frac12$ and squaring of $(S \cdot x)$ are a result of [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) (which is what the Greeks ultimately represent).

Comment: Sorry, why in yhe gamma PL you say that this is equal to delta*(S*0.001)^2?

Comment: See last sentence.

Comment: The justification for the GammaPnL formula is given here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/proof-of-gamma-profit-formula

Comment: So for a 1% move is it better to compute the delta PnL by multiplying the delta for the change in S or to compute it as the difference between the option value with the shocked S and with the unshocked S?